# forward a TCP connection with logging using socat

Tags: linux, networking, port-forwarding, socat

I'm trying to debug a service to which clients connect using TCP (in Linux).  I cannot change either program (don't have source), and I cannot make use of mechanisms which snoop on the network layer (like tcpdump, pcap, wireshark, etc).

I can configure each of service and client programs to listen or connect on whatever port or address binding I need.

I know it is possible to use the SOCAT program to forward arbitrary connections, using a command like `SOCAT -d -d TCP-LISTEN:2001,bind=127.0.0.1,fork TCP:localhost:2002` .  But I don't see that standard versions of socat have any mechanism for logging the data as it goes back and forth.

What I need is a way of forwarding a TCP connection in this fashion, but logging the data in both directions to a file (well, a pair of files).  Ideally this strategy would only use stock Linux packages, such as socat or tee.

I realize it's likely possible to write a program which does this, using Perl or Python or similar, but for the purposes of this question, I want a way of doing with using just glue (bash, etc) and stock programs.

Answer (score 7):

Add the `-v` option to print out the data being transferred:

```
SOCAT -v -d -d TCP-LISTEN:2001,bind=127.0.0.1,fork TCP:localhost:2002
```

In order to write it to a file add (Windows):

```
 1> log.log 2>&1
```

Comment: For my socat version (version 1.7.4.1), checkout `man socat`, there some helpful options like `-v`, `-x`, `-r <file>` and `-R <file>` .